# Postfix Problem (helo/hostname mismatch)!

Tags: postfix, spam, smtp

I have a server, and it is running a error for one email only (all other mails in that domain are working).

How can i fix it? (The error is above:)

```
May 17 11:43:56 webserver postfix/policyd-weight[5596]: weighted check:  IN_DYN_PBL_SPAMHAUS=3.25 NOT_IN_SBL_XBL_SPAMHAUS=-1.5 NOT_IN_SPAMCOP=-1.5 NOT_IN_BL_NJABL=-1.5 DSBL_ORG=ERR(0) CL_IP_NE_HELO=4.75 RESOLVED_IP_IS_NOT_HELO=1.5 HELO_NUMERIC=10.625 (check from: .eticagest. - helo: .[10.0.0.17]. - helo-domain: .17].)  FROM_NOT_FAILED_HELO(DOMAIN)=6.25; <client=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx> <helo=[10.0.0.17]> <from=MAIL@CLIENTDOMAIN.com> <to=ME@MYDOMAIN.com>; rate: 21.875 
May 17 11:43:56 webserver postfix/policyd-weight[5596]: decided action=550 Mail appeared to be SPAM or forged. Ask your Mail/DNS-Administrator to correct HELO and DNS MX settings or to get removed from DNSBLs; MTA helo: [10.0.0.17], MTA hostname: bl15-139-211.dsl.telepac.ptxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (helo/hostname mismatch); <client=188.80.139.211> <helo=[10.0.0.17]> <from=MAIL@CLIENTDOMAIN.com> <to=ME@MYDOMAIN.com>; delay: 6s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client doesn't had authentication on the SMTP Server. For some strage reason, it gaves this error.

Thanks all for the answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

The client `188.80.139.211` sent `EHLO 10.0.0.17` or `HELO 10.0.0.17` as a greeting to your mail server. According to [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) (section 4.1.1.1) the client should send its FQDN or (if none available) an address literal (e. g. its IP address).

So the correct greeting would be `EHLO bl15-139-211.dsl.telepac.pt` (or another valid FQDN pointing to the client) or `EHLO 188.80.139.211` if no meaningful hostname is available but definitely not `EHLO 10.0.0.17`.

Since the error occurs because of a misconfiguration of the client, you could only put the client on a whitelist to always accept its mails.

Comment: This client is using thunderbird, what can i do to corrent that?

Comment: I think the problem is that SMTP client isn't authenticating, i will confirm that

Comment: OK, the problem was on the SMTP Authenticating, the client wasn't authenticating. Thanks for your full answer. Your answer didn't solve my problem, but i will give +1 for the simpaty and details in the answer ;) (Here on Server Fault i can't vote up yet :( but when i can, i will vote ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
myhostname = host.example.com
```

in main.cf

Comment: that didn't solve, but thanks for your answer ;)